# How to generate AQIAAAAAAAUgAAAAIAIAAA== out of 'BUILTIN/Administrators' or 0x01020000000000052000000020020000

Tags: xml, reporting-services, active-directory, ssrs-2008, windows-authentication

I'm playing with automatically granting permissions to SSRS users using ReportServer.dbo.SetPolicy stored procedure and I'm stuck with updating @XmlPolicy field which contains the following:

@XmlPolicy  = 'BUILTIN\AdministratorsAQIAAAAAAAUgAAAAIAIAAA==Content Manager'

The GroupUserId above is obviously the SID of BUILTIN\Administrators account which is 0x01020000000000052000000020020000.

The question is how can I convert (encode) 0x01020000000000052000000020020000 to the AQIAAAAAAAUgAAAAIAIAAA== format?

Or is there a better way to do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`AQIAAAAAAAUgAAAAIAIAAA==`" is just the binary string `01 02 00 00 00 00 00 05 20 00 00 00 20 02 00 00` encoded in [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).